# How does R check for system external dependencies when installing an R package?

Tags: r

For instance, while trying to install the R package `curl` as a dependency of `usethis`:

```
* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
```

R detects that I don't have libcurl installed. At what level is this external dep. specified? I know that external dependencies can be indicated in the DESCRIPTION file, and indeed curl's pkg DESCRIPTION file does contain:

```
SystemRequirements: libcurl: libcurl-devel (rpm) or libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb).
```

But is that line what allowed R to detect the missing dependency and print that error? Can't be, right? How could it? So, how is R doing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Briefly:

1. This is all in [*Writing R Extension*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html).
2. In short, it doesn't *i.e.* R does not help you. See below.
3. CRAN (and Bioconductor) *package* dependencies can be declared.
4. For everything else you can only *approximate* via `SystemRequirements` in `DESCRIPTION`
5. This is not a solved or solvable problem of *all depends* across *all operating systems*
6. So no other language has it either.
7. What one can get is a package manager in a 'vertical' stack -- say `brew` or `apt`.  That is pretty good, but it also does *not work at the CRAN source level*.
8. So all one can do is, as you show, invoke something executable called `configure` to *test* if resources are present, and to abort with clear errors if not.
9. For the package you show, that [test code in `configure` is here](https://github.com/jeroen/curl/blob/master/configure).
10. There is a sibbling [Windows version too](https://github.com/jeroen/curl/blob/master/configure.win).